# How to consume HttpResponse in Akka Http

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpMethods, HttpRequest, Uri}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}
import spray.json._

import java.util.UUID
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object SoftwareRegistry extends App with Formatter {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("NPMRegistry")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  case class NPMPackage(name: String)

  // reading the packages
  val filename = "B:\\Scala\\NPMRegistry\\src\\main\\resources\\packages.txt"
  val bufferedSource = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename)
  val listOfPackages: List[NPMPackage] = (for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) yield {
    NPMPackage(line.trim)
  }).toList
  bufferedSource.close()

  // requests
  val serverHttpRequests = listOfPackages.map(pkg =>
    (HttpRequest(
      HttpMethods.GET,
      uri = Uri(s"/${pkg.name}")
    ),
      UUID.randomUUID().toString)
  )

  // source
  val sourceList = Source(serverHttpRequests)
  val bufferedFlow = Flow[(HttpRequest, String)]
    .buffer(10, overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    .throttle(1, 3 seconds)

  val dd = sourceList
    .via(bufferedFlow).async
    .via(Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[String]("registry.npmjs.org"))
    .runForeach {
      case (Success(response), oId) =>
        println(s"$oId $response")
      case (Failure(ex), oId) => println(ex)
    }
```

In the above code, I can print the response to the console and I want to know how to consume entity and access the data from the response in a streamed way, not in a future.

Following is the result of the existing code
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "streamed way"? How you want to use HTTP responses that you receive?

Comment: @Ava I want to consume the responses as they receive. I tried another method earlier; it gives all the responses in a future and I could use them after the future is completed. Here I want responses one by one

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to keep you logic within Akka Streams API and not terminating it with `runForEach` like you did.

A simplified example of this can look like this:

```scala
.via(Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[String]("registry.npmjs.org"))
    .flatMapConcat {
      case (Success(response), _) => Source.single(response)
      case (Failure(_), _) => Source.empty //warning, ignoring errors
    }
    .map(httpResponse => httpResponse.entity)
    .flatMapConcat(e => e.getDataBytes().map(bytes => ???))
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Instead of `runforEach` I am `flatMapConcat`enating  to get the `HttpRespnse` ignoring errors and the context of the request for simplicity of the example. Then `map`ping to get `HttpEntity` and then `flatMapConcat`enating again to get the `ByteString`s representing the response body. There could be multiple of those coming form every `HttpRequest` and that's, what I am guessing you're referring to by "streamed way".